# KeyCloak should be used as auth server for my users?

Tags: authentication, authorization, auth0, keycloak

So I want to have single sign in, in all the products using a auth server but that's not only for employees, keycloak should be used to that like auth0?

Comment: Sorry, your question was unclear. If you are asking whether Auth0 can offer SSO between applications, and also offer SSO behaviour for both B2E (federated) enterprises, as well as B2C (social etc) then yes Auth0 can certainly be used for that. You would not need keycloak to achieve any of the above - if you are already using keycloak, then federation between auth0 and keycloak is also achievable, but am speculating on your particular scenario here..

Comment: I'm sorry @arcseldon, So the case is that we are an app that anyone can download on play store, we want to know if keycloak could be used in our case to do the user authentication because we are planning to do another apps and we want single sign in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both Auth0 and Keycloak should be able to achieve your goal - assuming you want only social (facebook, google etc), and /or username & password authentication?

Auth0 is the less risky option, keycloak is good for non-commercial & where you can afford production outages without a global 24x7 support team. Here a few other reasons why I'd recommend Auth0 - the documentation is world class, they have quickstart samples so you can get up and running in minutes, and easy access to more advanced options - passwordless, authentication, MFA, anomaly detection, x9's reliability, rate-limiting, an extensive management api, extensions for everything eg exporting logs to log aggregator, and so on.  Anyhow, good luck with your project, and obviously what suits best may simply be down to your own project requirements.

Should add, if you are doing mobile, then Auth0 put a lot of effort into adding the necessary specialised security flows to target mobile (native / hybrid) apps. For instance, PKCE usage when using `/authorize` endpoint. Please bear that in mind, as not certain how keycloak has been implemented to handle this - alot of IDMs still do this incorrectly today.

Comment: Someone double downvoted today. Please, can you leave a comment explaining your action if you think it would help the quality of the answer provided? Thanks.

Comment: To be fair though, your answer seems to me a bit one-sided. It's a bit misleading to say that Keycloak is good for "non-commercial" projects, because neither Keycloak's license nor its features limit you to open-source projects. In 2020 Keycloak has all the features off Auth0 incl. PKCE

Comment: If you work for Auth0 you should probably disclose that.

Comment: Why is Keycloak more prone to outages? It's self hosted, it's as prone to outages as any part of your app if you don't take proper care of it.

Comment: I would have assumed that you  would disclose you were employed by Auth0 when writing an answer like that. I think it reflects poorly on you and Auth0.

Answer (score 33):

There are also some advantages to Keycloak:

Keycloak **is** also available with support if you buy JBoss EAP (see http://www.keycloak.org/support.html). This might be cheaper than the enterprise version of Auth0. If you want to use custom DB, you need enterprise version of Auth0 anyway.

Keycloak has features which are not available in Auth0:
Fine-grained permissions and role-based access control (RBAC) and attribute-based access control (ABAC) configurable via web admin console or custom code or you can write yuour own Java and JavaScript policies. This can be also implemented in Auth0 via user rules (custom JavaScript) or Authorization plugin(no code, less possibilities). In Keycloak you can do more without code (there are more types of security policies available out of the box e.g. based on role, groups, current time, an origin of the request) and there is a good support for custom developed access control modules. Here some more detailed research would be interesting to compare them.

Keycloak also offers a policy enforcer component - which you can connect to from your backend and verify whether the access token is sufficient to access a given resource. It works best with Java Web servers, or you can just deploy an extra Java Server with Keycloak adapter which will work as a gatekeeper and decide which request go through and which are blocked. All this happens based on the rules which you can configure via Keycloak web interface. I am not sure such policy enforcer is included in Auth0. On top of that, Keycloak can tell your client application which permissions you need when you want to access a given resource so you do not need to code this in your client. The workflow can be:

1. Client application wants to access resource R.
2. Client application asks Keycloak policy enforcer which permission it needs to access resource R.
3. Kecloak policy enforcer tells the client application which permission P it needs.
4. The client application requests an access token with permission P from Keycloak.
5. The client makes a request to the resource server with the access token containing permission P attached.
6. Policy enforcer which guards the resource server can ask Keycloak whether permission P is enough to access resource R.
7. When Keycloak approves, the resource can be accessed.

Thus, more can be centralized and configured in Keycloak. With this workflow, your client and resource server can outsource more security logic and code to Keycloak. In Auth0 you probably need to implement steps 2,3,6 on your own.

Comment: Is keycloak suitable for non-java severs? Do we need to roll something of our own in that case ?

Comment: Java servers have the best support when it comes to Policy enforcer provided by Keycloak. Node.js has limited support, there is a ticket open for improvement. You could always have a Java server running with Keycloak policy enforcer which only proxies authorized requests to your resource server. Or you can make authorization decisions based on the content of the requesting party token (then you only need the simpler entitlement API). But then you are implementing your own access control solution. See http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#authorization-api

Comment: I was curious specifically about the authorization part and it appears that auth0 also has support for it: https://auth0.com/docs/rules/current. It seems that Keycloak's offering is more advanced, but, I guess, if you have a piece of JS code that runs at the right moment, the rest is up to you. Keycloak offers an adapter and with auth0 you deal with what is in the access token (JWT).